# Why is stating a reason not required when closing a question?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

A few of my questions are closed and no reason is ever provided.. this is incredibly annoying, why was closing questions like the following allowed?

Examples:

- https://superuser.com/questions/209110/does-fennec-work-on-motorola-charm-closed
- https://superuser.com/questions/214378/rds-configuration-is-not-available-to-me-after-instlaling-coldfusion-8-eclipse-ex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its actually quite simple why your questions were closed/migrated:

those questions do not belong on Super User.

The FAQ clearly states that questions asked on Super User are NOT about:

> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

This means that your android device (an electronic device) is not covered.  Yes one could reason that the android software is an "*operating system*", however so is the ios software in iPhones, and any other "*operating software systems*" out there.  This is a site meant for the **Personal Computer** and **anything** relating to that.  If your question is about a connection between the device and the PC then it is on-topic.  If it's about **just** the device then it is NOT on-topic.

Your second question belongs on stackoverflow because is it code/programming related. This question was actually not closed but rather migrated to the sister site.

Finally, reasons do not need to be given on why a question was closed besides what is already automatically given as the stated reason of close.  If it's off-topic, it will be closed.  If it does not belong on Super User but on another site it will be migrated and closed here.  With the high amount of questions that are closed mods and 3k+ users cannot and will not be able to comment on every question that is closed.  It is your responsibility to make sure that the question is within the bounds of the stated [guidelines](https://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 4):

There is an explanation, it's right there on the post:

> #### closed as off topic by Sathya, ricbax, Diago Nov 10 at 10:53
>
> Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](https://superuser.com/faq).

See the faq section Kronos quoted!